# .upcase! makes if statement fail to work properly

Tags: ruby, if-statement, while-loop, upcase

```
begin
puts "Enter selection:\n\n"
$main = gets.chomp

        if $main.upcase! == "A"
                    call_function_1
        elsif $main.upcase! == "B"
                    call_function_2
        end

end while $main != "~"
```

With the code as it is, entering A runs call_function_1, but entering B seems to be ignored.

The issue appears to be the .upcase! , as when I remove it, it works fine... why?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_if_else.htm
Pretty sure, i could be wrong. You need the else in your if statement.

Comment: What do you mean, "only the first one is processed"?

Comment: Your code worked fine when I tested it

Comment: Your code is fine, if you didn't mess up with the indentation.

Comment: If I enter B at the prompt, it ignores the input and does not call call_function_2. If I then swap the two, it will ignore A and not call call_function_1.

Comment: OK. I tried the code all by itself, and it works fine there. I must have something crazy going on in my main program. I thought I was up against some limitation of a while loop, but it's most likely my newbie code. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Crud. It was $main.upcase! (which I left out of the example)... when I removed the .upcase!, it all works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `upcase`, not `upcase!`. I would also use a `case` statement instead of the `if` block.

```
begin
  puts "Enter selection:\n\n"

  input = gets.chomp

  case input.upcase
  when 'A'
    call_function_1
  when 'B'
    call_function_2
  end

end while $main != "~"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your code particularly, but you may be having a common beginner's mistake to use destructive methods when you shouldn't. `upcase!` will return `nil` when no upcase takes place, and that may be causing your problem. Especially, you are doing `upcase!` on a string `$main`, and then doing `upcase!` on it again. If there were no upcasing in the first `upcase!`, then you would be calling the second `upcase!` on `nil`, which will raise an error. Even if there were upcasing in the first `upcase!`, the second upcasing will surely not take place, and you will get `nil` even in that case. It does not makes sense at all. Change `upcase!` to `upcase`.

By the way, I don't understand why you are using `chomp` correctly (instead of `chomp!`), but are using `upcase!` (instead of `upcase`). And I also don't understand why you are using the former chained after `gets` (which is okay) but are doing the latter within each condition in `if` `elsif` `end` block (which is not only redundant, but problematic).

Furthermore, it looks like you should be using `case` `end` instead.

Comment: when I first wrote it, it said something like "unrecognized variable 'upcase'", but when I added ! then it worked. I am very new to programming so it is likely I am doing MANY things the wrong way, but thank your for the help. 私はまだ未熟者プログラマーだから、助けてくれましたありがとうございます。